# Check box toggle option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I think I may be overthinking my problem.

I have 3 checkboxes using the bootstrap-toggle css. I have 3 checkboxes but 
my condition is as such:

IF "Blue" and "Yellow" are checked, THEN "Green" will be checked and the other 2 will be unchecked. So long as "Green" is checked "Blue" and "Yellow" cant be checked. They don't need to disabled if "Green" is checked.
I would like use a javascript file unless this can be done in less code with Jquery. Open to either.

UPDATE: I provided the shorthand version of the HTML which may have thrown off how the "toggle" is handled. Please see the edited HTML below. In this case I found that the class of the div ***"toggle btn btn-default"*** needs to be switched from ***"toggle btn btn-success off"***

**CODE SNIPPET EDITED**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="blue">Blue
   <div class="toggle btn btn-success off" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
       <input name="blue" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
           <div class="toggle-group">
                <label class="btn btn-default toggle-on">No</label>
                <label class="btn btn-success active toggle-off">Yes</label>
           <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="yellow">Yellow
   <div class="toggle btn btn-success off" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
       <input name="yellow" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
           <div class="toggle-group">
                <label class="btn btn-default toggle-on">No</label>
                <label class="btn btn-success active toggle-off">Yes</label>
           <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="green">Green
   <div class="toggle btn btn-success off" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
       <input name="green" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
           <div class="toggle-group">
                <label class="btn btn-default toggle-on">No</label>
                <label class="btn btn-success active toggle-off">Yes</label>
           <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

I like the script that Mohit provide. However since the change isn't made by changing the input type, the script would have to change the div class instead. Thanks for your help guys!

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (event) {
        if(!$("input[type='checkbox'][name='blue']").is('checked') && !$("input[type='checkbox'][name='yellow']").is('checked'))
          {
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='green']").prop('checked', true);
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='blue']").prop('checked', false);
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='yellow']").prop('checked', false);

          }
          else if(!$("input[type='checkbox'][name='green']").is('checked'))
          {
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='blue']").prop('checked', false);
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='yellow']").prop('checked', false);
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried because your .js doesn't match up with your html as all?

Comment: Yes. As i mentioned above I was going to use the javascript i provided as a starting point and modify it to suite my needs. I know it does not match.

Comment: @cpt-crunchy: if the yellow and blue are checked and then only green can be checked, is it what you're looking for ? till the time green can be disabled.

Comment: @MohitTanwani: If blue and yellow are checked then green will be checked as a result and blue and yellow will uncheck. I don't want green to be disabled. Or if yellow and green are checked then green will remain checked but yellow will be unchecked

Comment: @cpt-crunchy: check my answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got what you're looking for in the fiddle below.  I've got it set up so if other colors are added (other than blue and yellow) and we want them to behave like blue and yellow we won't need to make any code changes.  The logic is if green is checked => uncheck all others and don't let them be selected.  If all others are checked => select green and uncheck all others.  More comments are available in the code:

[Fiddle w/ solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tburki/hymy6oyb/)

```
var $green = $('.button[name="green"]'), //Get our special input, "green"
    $notGreen = $('.button').not($green); //Get all other inputs

$('.form-group').on('change', '.button', function() { //Attach handler at parent and delegate to .button class
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { return; } //Only want to act when something is being checked

    if ($green.is(':checked')) {
        //If green is checked, want to uncheck everything else
        $notGreen.prop('checked', false); //.prop is the best way to uncheck
    }
    else if ($notGreen.filter(':checked').length === $notGreen.length) {
        //If every other input other than green is checked, check green and uncheck everything else
        $notGreen.prop('checked', false);
        $green.prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Here's the more generalized code from the comments that supports multiple groupings: [Generalized fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tburki/1o9d6v4b/1/)

Check below fiddle code.

```js
var $green = $('.button[name="green"]'), //Get our special input, "green"
    $notGreen = $('.button').not($green); //Get all other inputs

$('.form-group').on('change', '.button', function() { //Attach handler at parent and delegate to .button class
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { return; } //Only want to act when something is being checked
    
  if ($green.is(':checked')) {
      //If green is checked, want to uncheck everything else
      $notGreen.prop('checked', false); //.prop is the best way to uncheck
    }
    else if ($notGreen.filter(':checked').length === $notGreen.length) {
      //If every other input other than green is checked, check green and uncheck everything else
      $notGreen.prop('checked', false);
      $green.prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="blue">Blue
        <input name="blue" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>   
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="yellow">Yellow
        <input name="yellow" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="green">Green
        <input name="green" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for!

Comment: How would you code work if say there was another group of colors such as Red, Yellow2, Orange. Same premise but in this case Orange would be the "Green".

Answer (score 1):

Try following snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (event) {
        if($("input[type='checkbox'][name='blue']").is(':checked') && $("input[type='checkbox'][name='yellow']").is(':checked'))
          {
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='green']").prop('checked', true);
          }
        else
          {
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='green']").prop('checked', false);
          }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="blue">Blue
        <input name="blue" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>   
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="yellow">Yellow
        <input name="yellow" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="green">Green
        <input name="green" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. I've seen code similar to this, but this is not the function I was looking for. However, it does help me better organize my thoughts and how the javascript should be created.

Comment: Shakir kinda took your answer and just modified it to answer the question. Ruthless. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (event) {
        if($("input[type='checkbox'][name='blue']").is(':checked') && $("input[type='checkbox'][name='yellow']").is(':checked'))
          {
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='green']").prop('checked', true);
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='yellow']").prop('checked', false);
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='blue']").prop('checked', false);
            
          }
        else if($("input[type='checkbox'][name='green']").is(':checked'))
          {
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='blue']").prop('checked', false);
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='yellow']").prop('checked', false);
          }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="blue">Blue
        <input name="blue" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>   
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="yellow">Yellow
        <input name="yellow" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="green">Green
        <input name="green" class="button" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="No" data-off="Yes" data-onstyle="default" data-offstyle="success">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This works as well. However both suggestions seem to have problems when I use Bootstrap-toggle css. Not sure if the javascript is having issues with that CSS. http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Comment: How would you make the change not for the input type but the class?

Comment: @cpt-crunchy  I can't undestand what are you asking??